# jQuery script clears form data but should spare one input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following script with a contact form, on OK it clears the `input, textarea` but unfortunately it also clears the `submit` buttons SEND text. How could I spare this field?

Thank you

**The Form**

```
        <input class="required inpt" type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" /><br />
        <input class="required inpt" type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="E-Mail" /><br />
        <textarea class="required textbox" name="message" rows="6" cols="30" placeholder="Comments" ></textarea><br />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="Send" />
```

**The jQuery**

```
var close_note = $("#note");
close_note.click(function () {
    jQuery("#note").slideUp(1000, function () {
        jQuery(this).hide();
    });
});

$("#ajax-contact-form").submit(function() {
    $('#load').append('<center><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Currently Loading" id="loading" /></center>');
    var fem = $(this).serialize(),
        note = $('#note');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contact.php",
        data: fem,
        success: function(msg) {
            if ( note.height() ) {          
                note.slideUp(1000, function() {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
            } 
            else note.hide();
            $('#loading').fadeOut(300, function() {
                $(this).remove();
                if(msg === 'OK') {   $("#ajax-contact-    form").find('input, textarea').val(""); }     
                // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and     hide the form
                result = (msg === 'OK') ? '<div     class="success">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>' : msg;
                var i = setInterval(function() {
                    if ( !note.is(':visible') ) {
                        note.html(result).slideDown(1000);
                        clearInterval(i);
                    }
                }, 40);    
            }); // end loading image fadeOut
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: No need to worry about your `js script`. Just change the `html input as a button`. `<button type="submit" id="submit">SEND</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing `$("#ajax-contact-form").find("input,textarea")`, this includes all input and textarea fields including `submit` button.

Exclude `submit` from your selection.

Try this:

```
$("#ajax-contact-form").find("input,textarea").not("input[type='submit']").val("");
```

OR:

```
$("#ajax-contact-form").find("input[type='text'],input[type='email'],textarea").val("");
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're resetting your fields using the line:

```
if(msg === 'OK') {   $("#ajax-contact-form").find('input, textarea').val(""); }
```

`input, textarea` is not very specific, so it hits all of your inputs. If you had css selectors available, you could use them. In your case, I might do:

```
if(msg === 'OK') {
    $("#ajax-contact-form").find('input:not([type=submit]), textarea').val("");
}
```